# AJAX Methods for Dyanmically Updating Webpage

Tags: ajax, ping, long-polling

I have a requirement to issue a continuous ping from a webserver, and send/display each result (success/fail) to the webbrowser. 
However this raised the questions :

1. What is the best method for sending multiple responses back to the
   client after a single (AJAX) request ?
2. How would you send a "stop sequence" back to the server to stop the ping.

Ive seen some articles around comment, long polling AJAX etc but would just like some clarification on the correct path to choose.

Thanks,

Comment: websockets would be best if you can do it